# Incorrect syntax near the keyword ON in JOIN

Tags: sql, join

Could anyone assist with this error? Someone else showed me how to create a join and as far as I can tell I duplicated it exactly, but with another table but I can't get it to work:

```
SELECT [ITEMID]
  ,[ITEMDATAAREAID]
  ,ITEM.[ITEMGROUPID]
  ,[ITEMGROUPDATAAREAID]
FROM [ELG_DynamicsAX_DWH].[dbo].[INVENTITEMGROUPITEM] AS ITEM
Join(Select[NAME] AS [ITEMGROUPNAME]
  ,[ITEMGROUPID]
FROM[ELG_DynamicsAX_DWH].[dbo].[INVENTITEMGROUP] AS INVENTGROUP ON INVENTGROUP.ITEMGROUPID = 
ITEM.ITEMGROUPID
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: select t1.c1, t2.cb from t1 join t2 on t1.cx = t2.cy

Comment: You forgot your closing bracket before last 'as'

Comment: my goal is to add the column NAME out of the second table but I'm not getting that with this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
   [ITEMID]
  ,[ITEMDATAAREAID]
  ,ITEM.[ITEMGROUPID]
  ,INVENTGROUP.[NAME] AS [ITEMGROUPNAME]
  ,[ITEMGROUPDATAAREAID]
FROM 
   [ELG_DynamicsAX_DWH].[dbo].[INVENTITEMGROUPITEM] AS ITEM
   Join [ELG_DynamicsAX_DWH].[dbo].[INVENTITEMGROUP] AS INVENTGROUP 
      ON INVENTGROUP.ITEMGROUPID = ITEM.ITEMGROUPID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [ITEMID]
      ,[ITEMDATAAREAID]
     ,ITEM.[ITEMGROUPID]
     ,[ITEMGROUPDATAAREAID]
     X.[ITEMGROUPNAME]
FROM [ELG_DynamicsAX_DWH].[dbo].[INVENTITEMGROUPITEM] AS ITEM
Join
(
   Select[NAME] AS [ITEMGROUPNAME]
     ,[ITEMGROUPID]
   FROM[ELG_DynamicsAX_DWH].[dbo].[INVENTITEMGROUP] AS INVENTGROUP
)X ON X.ITEMGROUPID =ITEM.ITEMGROUPID
```

Something like this

Comment: the query works now, but I'm not getting the NAME in my view.

Comment: Why not skip the subquery, it's only making it harder,

Comment: I'm really sorry but I'm pretty new at SQL, so I'm not sure what you mean by subquery? My goal is to add the column NAME to the first table based on the relationship between the ITEMGROUPID

Comment: @user19845843, look at Magnus' answer. That's the regular way to do a join.

Comment: Then please use query from Magnus